# Using "ogr2ogr -sql" without an input fiile

Tags: ogr2ogr

Lets say I just wanted to turn WKT to GeoJSON on the command line I could do this:

```
/opt/gdal-custom/bin/ogr2ogr -f CSV /vsistdout/  foo.sqlite \
-dialect sqlite \
-sql "SELECT AsGeoJSON(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-94.1748 26.90248,-94.1748 27.60567,-93.07617 27.60567,-93.07617 26.90248,-94.1748 26.90248))', 4326)) AS wktIntersection"
```

However I don't actually need the sqlite file. Is there some sort of null datasource I could use? I tried replacing foo.sqlite with /dev/null and /vsimemory/. Its just a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the SQLite [in-memory database](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html): `:memory:`

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV /vsistdout/  ":memory:" -dialect sqlite \
-sql "SELECT AsGeoJSON(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-94.1748 26.90248,-94.1748 27.60567,-93.07617 27.60567,-93.07617 26.90248,-94.1748 26.90248))', 4326)) AS wktIntersection"
```

Comment: Ok that seems to be the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a tiny Python script, e.g. `wkt2json.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions()
print(ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(sys.argv[1]).ExportToJson())
```

And use it with the WKT in double quotes as the first and only argument:

```
$ python wkt2json.py "POINT(4 5)"
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.0, 5.0 ] }
```